# dplyr mutate column with nearest value in external list

Tags: r, dplyr, match

I'm trying to mutate a column and populate it with exact matches from a list if those occur, and if not, the closest match possible.

My data frame looks like this:

```
index <- seq(1, 10, 1)
blockID <- c(100, 120, 132, 133, 201, 207, 210, 238, 240, 256)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(index, blockID))

   index blockID
1      1     100
2      2     120
3      3     132
4      4     133
5      5     201
6      6     207
7      7     210
8      8     238
9      9     240
10    10     256
```

I want to `mutate` a new column that checks whether `blockID` is in a list. If yes, it should just keep the value of `blockID`. If not, It should return the nearest value in `blocklist`:

```
blocklist <- c(100, 120, 130, 150, 201, 205, 210, 238, 240, 256)
```

so the additional column should contain

```
100 (match), 
120 (match), 
130 (no match for 132--nearest value is 130), 
130 (no match for 133--nearest value is 130), 
201, 
205 (no match for 207--nearest value is 205), 
210, 
238, 
240, 
256
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(blockmatch = ifelse(blockID %in% blocklist, blockID, ifelse(match.closest(blockID, blocklist, tolerance = Inf), "missing")))
```

I just put in `"missing"` to complete the `ifelse()` statements, but it shouldn't actually be returned anywhere since the preceding cases will be fulfilled for every value of `blockID`. However, the resulting df2 just has "missing" in all the cells where it should have substituted the nearest number. I know there are base R alternatives to `match.closest` but I'm not sure that's the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `if..else`. Your rule can simplified by saying that we always get the `blocklist` element with ***least absolute difference*** when compared to `blockID`. If values match then absolute difference is 0 (which will always be the least).

With that here's a simple base R solution -

```
df$blockmatch <- sapply(df$blockID, function(x) blocklist[order(abs(x - blocklist))][1])

   index blockID blockmatch
1      1     100        100
2      2     120        120
3      3     132        130
4      4     133        130
5      5     201        201
6      6     207        205
7      7     210        210
8      8     238        238
9      9     240        240
10    10     256        256
```

Here are a couple of ways with `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    blockmatch = blocklist[order(abs(blockID - blocklist))][1]
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(
    blockmatch = sapply(blockID, function(x) blocklist[order(abs(x - blocklist))][1])
  )
```

Thanks to @Onyambu, here's a faster way -

```
df$blockmatch <- blocklist[max.col(-abs(sapply(blocklist, '-', df$blockID)))]
```

Comment: `blocklist[max.col(-abs(sapply(blocklist,'-',df$blockID)))]`

Comment: @Onyambu That's great! added to the answer. Thanks!